Algorithm for bin packing identical bins with a min and max size
I feel like this is an obvious variant of the classic bin packing problem but I can't seem to find it referenced anywhere (google, stackoverflow, cs.stackoverflow, etc).
My problem is determining if a given set of items can be packed into any number of bins where:

Items to pack have a varying integer size that is any integer value
There is a fixed set of items, all known initially
Bins have a min and a max size they require. So, the total of sizes of their contained items must be min <= total <= max
There are an unlimited set of bins available, all identical

I'm OK finding any assignment of items to bins that works. Speed is the highest priority.
I'm looking for any known algorithm, or even the canonical name of the problem.
The best I've come up with so far is using some variant of a branch and bound algorithm. I was hoping that something simple like a first-fit algorithm would work, but given that there is a minimum bound for the bins, it seems like it would need at least some kind of backtracking to rearrange the items if it ends up with items that can't meet the minimum (which is why branch and bound is my best current solution)
This is for a natural language solver  that needs to find solutions to phrases like "2 girls ate 2 ice cream cones". It has to find all of the things in the world state that make the logical version of the phrase true. Words like "2" or "at least" or "many" put lower and upper bounds on the number of "items" that can be placed into the "bins" represented by the logical variables that the phrase gets turned into.

The problem is NP-hard, by an easy reduction from the partition problem (set each bin's min=max=K, where K is half of the sum of the item values), and I believe it is strongly NP-hard, by reduction from 3-partition.
An easy-to-implement solution is to represent it as an instance of integer linear programming, and use an off-the-shelf ILP solver.  Let $u_j$ be 1 if the $j$th bin is used (0 otherwise), and $x_{i,j}$ be 1 if item $i$ is assigned to bin $j$ (0 otherwise).  Then it is easy to encode the requirement that if $u_j=1$ then $\min_j \le \sum_i x_{i,j} v_i \le \max_j$, where $v_i$ is the value of the $i$th item.  In particular, you can use
$$\min_j - C(1-u_j) \le \sum_i x_{i,j} v_i \le \max_j + C(1-u_j),$$
where $C$ is a sufficiently large constant (e.g., larger than the sum of values of all items).  Then ask an off-the-shelf ILP solver to find any feasible solution.
ILP solvers basically implement branch-and-bound and other such heuristics internally, so it spares you from having to implement them yourself.

Thanks! Would you agree my problem as stated is a bin packing problem? Is it a  named variant?

@EricZinda, I agree it's a bin picking variant, and I don't know whether it has ben studied before.

thanks for the help D.W!
